# how to change [TencentOAuth class] to swift

Tags: swift

i'm new in ios,i have no idea about object-c ,so how to change `[className class]` to swift

the code like this
 `[ShareSDK connectQZoneWithAppKey:@"100371282"
                         appSecret:@"aed9b0303e3ed1e27bae87c33761161d"
                 qqApiInterfaceCls:[QQApiInterface class]
                   tencentOAuthCls:[TencentOAuth class]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
className.self
```

For example:

```
String.self    //returns String.Type
```

Comment: it become TencentOAuth.self(NSObject)  NSObject should be what

Comment: @user3933218: Just `TencentOAuth.self`. No parentheses.